# Extend Immutable.js field with custom interface in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js

Let's say property name is `field` which is basically an immutable object.  So `field.get('')` or any immutable methods exists on it.
However, I've my own interface for this field defined which overrides or not naturally extends the immutable field.

```
interface FieldProps  {
    field: {
        type: string;
        code: string;
        required: number;
    }
}

export default function FieldsComponent({ field = fromJS({}) }: FieldProps) {
    return (
        <>
            {field.get('type')}
        </>
    );
}
```

What I mean is if I do `field.get('')` it says `Property 'get' does not exist on type '{ type: string; code: string; required: number; }`

`field` is basically an object and thus Javascript Object.prototype methods are available. Similarly, Immutable methods should be available too.

Just wondering, why it does not do that automatically ?

If not, what comes to my mind is to extend  my custom interface `FieldProps` with the Immutable interface. However, I'm sure immutable doesn't ships with any types of it's own.

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. Can you try to rephrase that or provide some code that doesn't work the way you want it to?

Comment: Sure did update the same.

Comment: Immutable has it's own types. https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/Immutable.d.ts

Comment: "Just wondering, why it does not do that automatically?" Why would it do it automatically? Nowhere did you say your interface has anything to do with Immutable, it's just a POJO.

Comment: @AvinKavish. Almost skipped it. Was trying to find by Immutable.something in vscode which auto imports. Anyway, doing `interface FieldProps extends Map<any, any> {}` doesn't helps.
`

Comment: `Map<Key, Value>` is not what you need here. A map is a key-value pairing which needs to be homogeneous. as far as I know there's no concept of "If I ask for key `field` the value will be of type X`. All keys and all values must have the same time. I suggest you look into alternative data types for this. Also if your parameter is a map then destructuring it will not work

Comment: @apokryfos. Not sure why is this getting so complicated. But hope, the problem is understood.  field comes from  an object and is an object itself( wrapped by immutable fromJS() at it's origin of API call then it flows through props). Not sure where does separate data type leads to. What you did by ternary check was to type check the field if it's a Map. What I need is to access the same immutable properties along with defining my own interface. What's the best way if not `& Map<any, any>` ( which works by the way)

Comment: It might sound simple in the surface but it is not simple. `& Map<any, any>` might work but the problem there would be TypeScript cannot know that `field.get('required')` is a number and this might cause issues further downstream. The suggested way to do this is to use Immutable at your store level (e.g. using Redux or similar) and components themselves will receive plain objects but if those objects are mutated it would be of no consequence to the store since the store itself will be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want `field` to be a map with some added keys, you can create a type intersection in the following manner.

```
interface FieldProps  {
    field: {
        type: string;
        code: string;
        required: number;
    } & Map<any, any>
}
```